# Grid of 30 x 30 buttons

Tags: winapi, gdi, button

I'm making a grid of 30 x 30 buttons with BS_BITMAP representing some numeric value which can be set by clicking on buttons. so should I go creating 900 buttons on a window and or GDI would help to do something same?

Any ideas on setting a row of some column in a grid to some values? would I need a multidimensional array of window handles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

900 controls on a single window does seem a little overkill, Dave - I'd suggest creating a custom control that uses a single window and which renders button-like objects that respond to the usual events, rather than overloading the window with controls.  Windows may gripe at having so many controls on a single window - or could perform fairly slowly when the window gets invalidated etc.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Petzold has an example of a grid of button-like object in _Programming Windows_.  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Microsoft-Charles-Petzold/dp/157231995X

Comment: ah yes, I guess you meant the hex calculator.